# Collection function to return part of a collection, similar to forums?

Tags: mongodb

You know how theres pages in forums right? Say an internet forum has 1,000 threads and each page only displays 20 threads. How would you do that in Mongodb, given that I know what page I'm meant to be on?

I read up on the $slice method, but that seemed to be only for embedded arrays within items. How to make it so that if I'm on page 4, the collection.find returns only items from index 79-99?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
Db.find({}, {skip: 20 * page, limit: 20});
```